# 1997 Chevy Blazer: Will a TCM from a 2001 work in a 1997?

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, blazer

1997 Chevy Blazer 4.3 4x4. Transmission has only one forward gear. Will a TCM from a 2001 Chevy Blazer work in my 1997?

Had a trouble code for shifting solenoid a and b and tc and tcm.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!